# Can i install the ubuntu phone os in oracle virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, phone

I love the idea of the new Ubuntu Phone OS and was wanting to try it out.  Unfortunately, I don't have any extra Galaxy or Nexus sitting around my house.  So, I was wondering if I could install the Ubuntu Phone OS in Oracle VirtualBox or any of virtual machine software?

Comment: Virtualbox doesn't emulate processor architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly you cannot... Ubuntu Touch is an mobile OS designed for Tablets and Smartphones ( I don't know why only Nexus's are compatible for now )...
But, you can wait until it would have more compatibility to other systems, and install it in any of your devices (compatible with Ubuntu Touch of course)...